# Manually run a cron job / simulate running cron job?

Tags: cron

I want to test if cron's mailing stuff after an executed task and things like that work. Is there a more elegant way to test this, then setting a cron job to run every few seconds? So, is there any way to simulate the execution of a cron job / start a cron job manually, but with the same behaviour it would have when being run automatically by cron?

Comment: There is a better solution at http://serverfault.com/q/85893/75968

Comment: This is also discussed on Ask Ubuntu: ["Verify if crontab works"](http://askubuntu.com/q/85558/457111)

Answer (score 11):

The main difference between executing a cron job on the command line and inside cron is its environment. Other potential differences include the current directory, the availability of a terminal, and which shell is used.

This is a fairly accurate simulation of running a cron job via cron. To avoid differences due to the shell, put your job in a script and put only the path to that script in the crontab. Note that the exact set and values of environment variables passed by cron are implementation-dependent; check the `crontab(5)` man page on your system. `ifne` is a command that runs the command specified in arguments if it receives some input; there's one in [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

```
env -i HOME="$HOME" LOGNAME="$LOGNAME" PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bin/sh USER="$USER" \
    /path/to/script </dev/null 2>&1 |
ifne mail -r "Cron Daemon" -s "Cron <$USER@$(hostname)> /path/to/script" "$USER"
```

Another way of creating a cron-like setting is through [`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at). But `at` takes care of running the command with the environment variables that the `at` process received, so you still need to emulate this part.

```
echo /path/to/script |
env -i HOME="$HOME" LOGNAME="$LOGNAME" PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bin/sh USER="$USER" \
    at now
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I did it to simulate the cron execution of a script I've created years ago but which started failing recently.

I created a script called `dumpenv`:

```
#!/bin/sh

base=$(basename $0)

env -0 > /tmp/$base.$$.dump
```

This dumps all environment variables into a file in `/tmp/`. Then I modified my crontab to add:

```
*/1 * * * *  [path to newly created script]
```

This makes the script run every minute. So after a minute, I got a dump of the environment seen by tasks run from cron. If the crontab line is left to run more than a minute, it creates a bunch of identical files with names differing only in the pid part of the file name (`$$`). No biggie. I could have coded for this eventuality so as to get just one file but the main principle here is "good enough", and I might want to use `dumpenv` in other contexts where multiple dumps are useful. At any rate, it is advisable to remove the crontab line that was added so as to avoid populating `/tmp` with lots of junk.

Then I created an additional file which I called `/tmp/command` which contained the command I wanted to execute, on a single line **terminated by a null character.** The null character is necessary.

Then I issued:

```
cat [path to dumpfile crated earlier] /tmp/command | xargs -0 -x env -i
```

And this replicated the fault I saw when my command is executed from cron. What `xargs` does is build an command of the form:

```
env -i [list of environment variables] [command to execute]
```

and executes it. The list of environment variables comes from the dump file. The command that `env` executes comes from the `/tmp/command` file.

The `-0` arguments to `env` and `xargs` and the required null character I mention above is to prevent environment mangling while variables are being passed around. In cases where the environment contains no environment variable with a newline in it, `-0` could conceivably be omitted from the invocation of `env` in the `dumpenv` script and from the `xargs` command, and the `/tmp/command` file would not require a null character as a line terminator.

I do no explicit redirection of stdin to /dev/null because xargs does it for me. I also do not care about redirecting stdout/stderr, and I do not want to receive an email if the command fails. For cases where these features are desired, Gilles' answer provides the means to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Louis' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64077/72471) is great. I propose a slight possible improvement.

Instead of creating a file `/tmp/command` which contains the path to the script you want to execute as Louis suggested in the following code:

```
cat [path to dumpfile crated earlier] /tmp/command | xargs -0 -x env -i
```

Instead you can name the script directly in the command via the following alternate command (take note of the `\x00` appended to the cron script path, which is essential:

```
printf "/path/to/cron/script\x00" | cat /path/to/dumpfile/created/earlier - | xargs -0 -x env -i
```

This avoids any need to create a file `/tmp/command`.

Comment: Note: I edited my original post because I'd found a cleaner solution (using `printf` instead of `awk`)